What exactly IS Intellisense compared to tab completion or auto-complete?
I can't find a direct answer as to the definition of Intellisense used in the PowerShell ISE, and how it differs to auto-complete or would be used in the shell

Google is your friend "What is Intellisense", Top Answer explains it very well!
